# call method on click column menu

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am new to ag-grid. I am trying to add custom column menu item.

I wrote this in constructor:

```
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
     getMainMenuItems: this.addColumnMenu
};
```

So, Whenever I click filter icon of column, 'addColumnMenu' is called.

Now, in addColumnMenu, I have added my menu item as

```
 var menuItems = params.defaultItems.slice(0);
 menuItems.push({
           name: 'Stats', action: this.callStat }
 });
```

Its giving `this.callStat` is not defined. Because I am not getting anything in `this`

Whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If addColumnMenu needs to access 'this', then it needs to be bound. One way to achieve this:

```
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
  getMainMenuItems: this.addColumnMenu.bind(this)
};
```